# Random images, 2 different divs [HTML,JavaScript]

Tags: javascript, html, image, random

so I need some help. I have a small iphone site and I want the bars (4 images) to random at the same color. (like a theme)

So like this

```
Barred1.jpg , Barred2.jpg , Barred3.jpg Barred4.jpg
Barblue1.jpg , Barblue2.jpg , Barblue3.jpg Barblue4.jpg
Barpink1.jpg , Barpink.jpg , Barpink3.jpg Barpink4.jpg
Bargreen1.jpg , Bargreen2.jpg , Bargreen3.jpg Bargreen4.jpg
```

How do it?

All the bars are on different divs..

I'm sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 0):

You could have JavaScript choose a color at random (using [this technique](http://www.shawnolson.net/a/789/make-javascript-mathrandom-useful.html)) and then work through all images on the page like this:

```
var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName('img'),
i = imgs.length;
while (i) {
    i -= 1;
```

Then you could check the image's `src` attribute like so:

```
    if (/^Bar([a-z]+)\.jpg/.test(imgs[i].src)) {
```

If it matches, just switch out the src with the color your JS arrived at:

```
        imgs[i].src = 'Bar' + random_color + '.jpg';
```

Comment: Can you please give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

step 1 is to assign each color a number, then use random number to pick a color

```
var colors = new Array("red","blue","pink","green");

var random = Math.floor(Math.random()*4);
```

step 2 is to use a for loop to set the img src to the color

```
for (var i=1; i < 5; i++){

document.getElementById("img"+i).src = "Bar"+colors[random]+i+".jpg";

}
```

Comment: Oh geez.. Need some loop unwinding here.. No need for it (not that it REALLY matters all that much tho ;))

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

var a = ['red', 'blue', 'pink', 'green'];

function setBarTheme(bar, idx)
{
$(bar).css('background-image', 'url(Bar' + a[idx] + '.jpg)');
}

$(document).ready(function(){

var r = Math.floor(Math.random()*4);

setBarTheme('#bar1', r);
setBarTheme('#bar2', r);
setBarTheme('#bar3', r);
setBarTheme('#bar4', r);

});


</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="bar1"></div>
<div id="bar2"></div>
<div id="bar3"></div>
<div id="bar4"></div>

</body>
</html>
```